# Subtracting the first data off the rest

Tags: python, loops, matrix

What can I add to my function below for my `isotope['State_2_complete']` up to `isotope['State_640_complete']` to have values of:

`isotope['State_2_complete'] - isotope['State_1_complete']`, 
 `isotope['State_3_complete'] - isotope['State_1_complete']`, 
`isotope['State_4_complete'] - isotope['State_1_complete']`,
 ... `isotope['State_640_complete'] - isotope['State_1_complete']` ?

I thought it would be as simple as:

`isotope['State_{0}_complete'.format(i)] = isotope['State_{0}_complete'.format(i)] - isotope['State_1_complete']`

or something like:

`isotope['State_{0}_complete'.format(i)] -= isotope['State_1_complete']`

But both options were only subtracting `isotope['State_1_complete']` - `isotope['State_1_complete']` where I get 0 values for my `isotope['State_1_complete']` (which I want) but the rest of the states (e.g. `isotope['State_2_complete']`, `isotope['State_3_complete']`, ... `isotope['State_640_complete']`) stayed as their original values.

```
def create_relative_excitation_energies_66_x_640_matrix(isotope, data_tbd, data_occ):
    """
    creates a 66 x 640 matrix by subtracting off the 
    ground state data from the excited states
    """

    # counter
    a = 10
    b = 12
    # getting our 640 states in numpy array form
    for i in range (1,641):
        isotope['State_{0}_inc'.format(i)] = np.genfromtxt(data_tbd, names=('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'J', 'T', 'X_JT(ab,cd)'),
                                        skip_header=a, max_rows=63, usecols=6)
        
        isotope['State_{0}_inc'.format(i)] = np.expand_dims(isotope['State_{0}_inc'.format(i)], axis=1)
                                        
        isotope['State_{0}_inc'.format(i)] = isotope['State_{0}_inc'.format(i)].astype('float64')
                                             
        isotope['State_{0}_spe'.format(i)] = np.genfromtxt(data_occ, names=('Particle', 'occ', 'Orbit_1', 'Orbit_2', 'Orbit_3'),
                                        skip_header=b, max_rows=2, usecols=(2,3,4))
        
        isotope['State_{0}_spe_sum'.format(i)] = np.vstack((isotope['State_{0}_spe'.format(i)]['Orbit_1'].sum(),
                                        isotope['State_{0}_spe'.format(i)]['Orbit_2'].sum(), isotope['State_{0}_spe'.format(i)]
                                        ['Orbit_3'].sum()))
        
        isotope['State_{0}_complete'.format(i)] = np.vstack((isotope['State_{0}_inc'.format(i)], isotope['State_{0}_spe_sum'.format(i)]))

####### isotope['State_{0}_complete'.format(i)] = *add code here* ###########
     
        a += 66
        b += 3
    
    matrix = np.hstack(([isotope[f'State_{i+1}_complete'] for i in range(640)]))
    
    return matrix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're doing this:

```
isotope['State_{0}_complete'.format(i)] = np.vstack((isotope['State_{0}_inc'.format(i)], isotope['State_{0}_spe_sum'.format(i)]))
```

But you say you want to update these values by subtracting the first such value off of itself and all the other ones. So, you could replace the above with:

```
if first is None:
    first = np.vstack((isotope['State_{0}_inc'.format(i)], isotope['State_{0}_spe_sum'.format(i)]))
isotope['State_{0}_complete'.format(i)] = np.vstack((isotope['State_{0}_inc'.format(i)], isotope['State_{0}_spe_sum'.format(i)])) - first
```

And define `first = None` outside and before the loop. Since `first` will only be `None` on the first pass through, that's when it gets its value and for every assignment of those values, it will then be subtracted from them.

Comment: interesting... let me try that to see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: ooooohh it worked!! thank you thank you! you just saved me a lot of time!